# 301 Redirect but exclude subdirectories

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, seo, http-status-code-301

I'm creating 301 RedirectMatch entries in my .htaccess file and I'm having trouble figuring out how to redirect all the .html files to .php in the root folder, but not the child folders. Here's what I tried but it's not working:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]+).html /$1.php
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*).html /$1.php
```

These redirect all the .html in my child folders, too, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
^/([^/]*)\.(html|php)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it didn't work. I tried the following: `RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]*)\.html) $1.php` and `RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]*)\.(html|php)` but I just get 404 errors when I try and test it by loading the .html pages in the root directory.

Comment: Your answer spurred me on to find the solution since it was very close. Here's what worked: `RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^/]*)\.html $1.php`

Comment: Oh, well ... I don't know why I thought you want to redirect .php as well. Sorry about that. :)